# Apache camel intercept, update the Exchange message for all RouteBuilders, and continue

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

I have a `CamelConfiguration` that configures 15 `Routes`.

```
public class CamelRoutesConf extends CamelConfiguration {

     @Override
     public List<RouteBuilder> configure() {
        List<RouteBuilder> routes = super.routes();
        routes.forEach(router -> {
                  router.onException(Exception.class).delay(5000);
        });
        return routes;
     }
}
```

**What I want to achieve** is check the header of every incoming `Message` (`exchange.getHeaders()`) inside the route, and add a header if it doesn't exist.

I can achieve that using `Processor` inside each `RouteBuilder`. Ex.

```
public class ArtistHiredRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

  @Override
  public void configure(){
    from(incomingArtistsQ)
    .process(new Processor(){
        public void process(Exchange exchange){
            exchange.getIn().setHeader("JMSCorrelationId", randomNumberOfLength10());
        }
      })
    .to(outgoingArtistsQ)
}
```

Purpose is to use same id between all exchange messages, so that it becomes easier to relate them later.

So, is there a Camel way of doing this in `CamelConfiguration#configure` so that it applies to all the `Route`s.

I expected intercepting as below.

```
public class CamelRoutesConf extends CamelConfiguration {

     @Override
     public List<RouteBuilder> configure() {
        List<RouteBuilder> routes = super.routes();
        routes.forEach(router -> {
                  router.interceptFrom().process(headerProcessor)
                  router.onException(Exception.class).delay(5000);
        });
     }
}
```

It will be intecepted but doesn't seem to continue with `.to()` in each `RouteBuilder`.

### References

http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html

http://www.davsclaus.com/2009/05/on-road-to-camel-20-interceptors-round.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [interceptFrom()](http://camel.apache.org/intercept.html) clause to set your header value for all routes

```
// intercept all incoming routes and do something...
interceptFrom().setHeader(JMSCorrelationId", randomNumberOfLength10());
```

Comment: Tried similar approach with `.interceptFrom().process(myProcessor)` as well inside `CamelRoutesConf #configure`. But doesn't intercept at all. Is executed after `.from().to();` in each `RouteBuilder`s

Comment: Interesting, that actually does work. Let me dig more so that I can make it testable.

Comment: does interceptFrom() continues the routeBuilders `.to()` as it was, after intercepting `.from()`? I think it doesnt work that way??

Comment: my goal was to intercept the `from(Queue)` and then add header to the exchange and continue with `.to(Queue)`. I tried `"direct:addCorrelationId"` as well, no luck